# Add a new value in a row, next to old one separated by comma

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have in column `pushed_closed` the value '**09:51**'.

I need to add in column `pushed_closed`, next to value '**09:51**', value 2 like:

**09:51**,**09:54** (separated by commas).

My PHP code:

```
$connection = db_connect();
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];
        $ora_terminare = '09:54';
        mysqli_begin_transaction($connection);
        $query = mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE birouri SET closed_program = 'DA', pushed_closed = '$ora_terminare' WHERE username = '$username'");
        mysqli_commit($connection);
```

How to create the correct Mysqli query?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Don't do it.  Storing lists of things in columns is a really, really bad idea.  You should have a separate table with one row per value.

Comment: How to create the correct Mysqli query? This was the question.

Comment: Why - voting? Nice.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff . I went on building a separate table.

Comment: @BogdanC . . . Now you only need an `insert`.

Comment: Thank you. Please post an answer to select it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$connection = db_connect();
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$ora_terminare = '09:54';
mysqli_begin_transaction($connection);
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE birouri SET closed_program = 'DA', pushed_closed = concat(coalesce(pushed_closed, ''), ',', '$ora_terminare') WHERE username = '$username'");
mysqli_commit($connection);
```

Concating with old value will make it for you.

Comment: Nothing happens.

Comment: Error is: Incorrect parameters in the call to native function 'concat'

Comment: Try executing `select concat(coalesce('9:51', ''), ',', '9:54')` . If it works - please make sure that the end query that goes to mysql is `UPDATE birouri SET closed_program = 'DA', pushed_closed = concat(coalesce(pushed_closed, ''), ',', '9:54') WHERE username = 'someusername'` I'm not a php dev, but in MySQL it executes perfectly.

Comment: coalesce is for using PHP 7.

Comment: *"coalesce is for using PHP 7"* - @BogdanC huh? [coalesce](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html) has existed in mysql for ages and other RDBMS'

Comment: Indeed. I saw something related to null values coalesce.